# Kernel.lambda() not returning a lambda Proc in Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby, lambda, block, ampersand, ruby-1.9.3

I'm writing a simple event bus to use in an application. This part works fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

module EventBus
  @callbacks = {}

  module_function

  def on event, &callback
    @callbacks[event] ||= []
    @callbacks[event].push callback
  end

  def fire event, *data
    @callbacks[event].each do |callback|
      callback.call *data
    end
  end
end

EventBus.on :foo do |x| puts x end
EventBus.fire :foo, "test"
# => test
```

Because of the complex nature of my program, and the fact that `Proc`s take arguments in a very loosey-goosey fashion, I want some argument checking on my events. `lambda` is the obvious choice for this:

```
EventBus.on :bar, &(lambda do |x| puts x end)

# Will raise an ArgumentError, since the event was fired without any arguments
# Remember that this is the desired behavior
EventBus.fire :bar
```

Clearly, the syntax of the `on` call is ugly due to the `&(lambda do ... end)`. I'd rather be able to just use `do ... end` (i.e. just pass it a normal block without the unary ampersand operator) and convert that into a lambda. I tried the obvious:

```
...
  def on_lambda event, &callback
    @callbacks[event] ||= []
    @callbacks[event].push(lambda &callback)
    # check if the added callback is lambda. (spoiler alert: it isn't)
    puts @callbacks[event].last.lambda?
  end
end

EventBus.on_lambda :baz do |x| puts x end
# I would expect the callback to be a lambda, and thus throw an ArgumentError,
# but neither of these holds.
EventBus.fire :baz
```

As I understand it, `on_lambda` takes a block, converts it to a `Proc` referenced locally by `callback` (via the `&`). I'm pushing the result of calling `lambda` with `callback` converted back in to a block. I expect this to return a lambda derived from the `callback` `Proc`, so my question is: **why is the element on the array a normal `Proc`.**?

```
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
```

---

*Update:*
Prompted by megas's mention of `{ }` I looked into the `->() { }` syntax (I've seen it called the "stab" operator). It produces a lambda from the block specified. It's probably as close as I'll get to the mixture of normal block syntax and argument checking I wanted. All I have to do is tweak the `on` method:

```
def on event, callback
  @callbacks[event] ||= []
  @callbacks[event].push callback
end
```

and then attach callbacks like so:

```
EventBus.on :bam, ->(x) do
  puts x
end
```

I'm still curious as to the original question, however.

Comment: What about code convention to use {} for one line block?

Comment: That works equivalently to `do ... end` as far as I know, except for the precedence. The callbacks will almost never be a single line in my application, and using that syntax does not produce a lambda Proc either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest reading this: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Proc.html#method-i-lambda-3F

Comment: RTFM. An old classic. Specifically: "`lambda`, `proc` and `::new` preserve the tricks of a `Proc` object given by `&` argument."

Answer (score 1):

Blocks passed to method calls are always packaged as Procs. If you want lambdas, you must construct them explicitly, by saying lambda {|...| ... }. Btw. I also like lambdas better than procs, but if I remeber well, Matz in his tutorial introduces procs as "more featureful" than lambdas (procs "have tricks" of adapting to variable number of arguments etc., lambdas don't).

You'd have to do something like this to pass lambdas in:

```
def on_lambda event, callback
  (@callbacks[event] ||=[]) << callback
  puts @callbacks[event].last.lambda?
end

EventBus.on_lambda :baz, lambda do |x| puts x end
EventBus.fire :baz
```

Comment: That all makes sense to me, but in `on_lambda` I'm passing the Proc back in to `lambda` via the unary `&` operator, which should convert it back to a block (which should be why `lambda` doesn't raise an `ArgumentError` itself, if I understand correctly).

Comment: Also, the `Proc`'s "tricks" are generally beautiful, but specifically undesirable in this case because I want strict argument checking.

Comment: As soon as you start packaging and unpackaging blocks with & ... which is not really operator, but more something like splash * for blocks ... I mean, once you start wit &, you're stuck with procs. I suggest that you patch your Kernel with alias :λ :lambda ^_^